# Displaying the contents of a CSV file in a UIPicker

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, csv, uipicker

I was wondering what the best way of displaying the contents of a CSV file in a UIPicker would be.

The idea is that a person picks a date range in a UIPicker and then gets a UIAlert popup based on their selection.

I know there are probably a few options. I thought there might be something simple where I can avoid making a database.

My CSV file has 4 columns. One of the columns is a date range column and is written like:

```
Feb 20, 1920 - Feb 7, 1921
Feb 8, 1921 - Jan 27, 1922
Jan 28, 1922 - Feb 15, 1923
Feb 16, 1923 - Feb 4, 1924
etc....
```

thanks for any help.

Comment: I think the difficult part here is to parse all the dates, so that you can compare them to the user entered date. Doing this every time in memory may create a performance problem. On the other hand you could create an in memory representation and reuse this. How many rows does the CSV have? Do you already have a parser for that file?

Comment: thanks for your response. there are 104 rows. the user won't enter a date, but simply scroll the uipicker to the relevant date range and then get a UIAlert with a value from another column in the same row as the date range.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could build an incredibly simple CSV parser just using methods of `NSString`.

You can read in the contents on the CSV using

```
+ (id)stringWithContentsOfFile:(NSString *)path encoding:(NSStringEncoding)enc error:(NSError **)error
```

You can then split the string to get an array where each object represents a line in the file using

```
- (NSArray *)componentsSeparatedByString:(NSString *)separator
```

passing `@"\n"` as the separator

Once you have this array, you can then loop through it and use the same method to split each line up by passing `@","` as the separator (*assuming your columns are comma delimited, although in your case it seems the delimeter may be something else?*)

```
NSString *contents = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
NSArray *rows = [contents componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];
for (NSString *row in rows) {
    NSArray *values = [row componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
    // do something with the values here
}
```

Comment: Given the above code, I think the column separator is likely to be @"\t" (tab), instead of @",". But otherwise this seems the way to go.

Comment: You are correct; I've updated my code to reflect your comment.